# Can't understand why this python code isn't working

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am new to python programming. Why does this code does not work?

```
# Print out 2,5,8,11 using `for` loop and `range()`.
for x in range (2,12):
  print (x)
  x=x+3
```

I know the following will make the program work

```
# Print out 2,5,8,11 using `for` loop and `range()`.
for x in range (2,12,3):
  print (x)
```

But I can't understand why the first one doesn't give the desired result whereas the equivalent code would work in C++/C.

Comment: x is set from range on every iteration, overwriting the x incremented inside the loop. Note that x is just a name, its value is separate from previous values held by x. It is range that holds the state.

Comment: Python doesn't work like other languages where the loop variable can be directly messed with. Use a `while` loop if you want to achieve functionality similar to that.

Comment: You "can't understand why the first one doesn't" … doesn't what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even you try to increment **x** as `x=x+3`, it is being changed in every iteration, and take the new value from 2 to 12, depending upon how many iteration has been progressed( if the loop is in 4th cycle, then x will be updated as **4** at the start of the 4th cycle). Even if you've placed `x=x+3`before the `print` statement, what it will do is simply printing **"iteration + 3"**

```
for x in range (2,12):
print (x)
x=x+3
```

So this code will produce an output like this;

**5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14**

So, there is no way to update `x` and then use this updated version in next iteration when you are using a **for loop** in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increment the value of **x** when using **range()** function. There are two ways you can get your desired output.

First Method :

**print [x for x in range(2,12,3)]**

Second Method :

**for x in range(2,12, 3):**

**print(x)**